# Kolab 3 outbound mails spam detection

Tags: spamassassin, spam-filter

I installed Kolab on a local server and I need a way to allow it to reject spam mails before they are sent.

One method that I found is to install postfix and spamassassin in another server and forward all mails through it, the spamassassin will filter spams the postfix will forward them to there destination.

Is there any other way?

Can I configure spamassassin which installed along side kolab to do the same?